# Mvc: pass id but not show it in friendly url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, friendly-url

I have a view that renders a list of news, in that i have an href tag, and i need to call a Detail method and pass it the news id, now i have a querystring in my url like that
News/Details?id=x... but i need something like News/Details/Category/Title-of-something, a friendly url with news category, name and without the id

this is my action, it works but i get that querystring

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "News", new { id = item.newsId, category = item.categoryName, name = item.newsName })' title=""> Read More </a>
}
```

I was trying with something like, with a Url.RouteUrl

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Details",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{category}/{newsName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Details"}
        );
```

but it never goes to Details actionresult, and also i need to pass the id parameter for showing some news Details, but i don't want to display it in the friendly url. Im really confused how to achieve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: the routing maybe overridden by other route. So, copy this route and move it to the top. I mean, place this route on the top of the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Read More", "Details", new { action = "Details", id = item.newsId, category = item.categoryName, newsName = item.newsName })
```

Comment: It works perfect, so now i can send multiple parameters to my ActionResult and i have and url friendly with something like, News/Details/Id/Category/Title-of-something, routes.MapRoute was right, so you know how can i send the id to my Action Result, and have my url with something like News/Details/Category/Title-of-something whithout the id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Details", "News", new { id = item.newsId, category = item.categoryName, newsName = item.newsName })' title=""> Read More </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your route is not overridden by other route. So put your route first in RoutConfig.cs
Change your code to:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "News", new { id = item.newsId, category = item.categoryName, newsName = item.newsName })' title=""> Read More </a>
}//change name=item.newsName to newsName=item.newsName
```

Also make sure that your controller has correct signature as per your routing details:

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(int id, string category, string newsName )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First URL Correct

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Details", "News", new { id = item.newsId, category = item.categoryName, newsName = item.newsName })' title=""> Read More </a>
```

You may [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx)  whenever yo see issue related to routes